# How do I run a GUI file as a thread from another class in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, runnable

The default GUI code when you use window builder is the following.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Goo {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Goo window = new Goo();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Goo() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

I want to run this from another class as a thread. So the other class will look like,

```
public class GooRun {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Goo myGoo = new Goo();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(myGoo);
    myThread.start();

}
}
```

I dont fully understand how the run method works when you are not using implements Runnable or extends Thread.

The error I get is that the constructor is undefined Thread(Goo) is undefined.

Comment: I may be missing the point of your program but why do you have a main method in both classes?

Comment: @ JackVanier, one class will have to run to call the other also to run

Comment: What exactly do you want to do inside `myThread`??? Remember that Swing, as AWT and all the systems based on it, is not multithreading safe. Everything you do on the GUI (setting visible, changing texts and othe things like that) must be done on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) using the `EventQueue` class just as the window builder does. [Read mode about this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

first option: make `myGoo` implement `Runnable`:

```
public class Goo implements Runnable{
```

and then add a `run` method in `Goo`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Goo window = new Goo();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and after that, you can do as you did in the other `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Goo myGoo = new Goo();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(myGoo);
    myThread.start();
}
```

Basically, this makes `Goo` into something that can be started when a thread starts (hence the implementation `Runnable`).

## OR

option 2: in your `main`, you can create a thread with a runnable:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Goo myGoo = new Goo();      
            
        }
    });
    t.start(); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah @ romarshmallow, you can still wait to get more alternatives even though this one worked, before choosing one as best for you. Right now that you have mark one as best answer, no or few people will contribute further to your question. All the same this answer is **cool**.

Answer (score 0):

ItamarG3's solution 1 is actually a bad idea.
In that case you are having 2 instances (one from `run()` and one from `main()`) of `Goo` while you don't need them.

You should call `this.frame.setVisible(true);` in the `run()` and do not `new` another `Goo` instance.